# android - Notification title cut off

Tags: android, notifications

I have the following code to show the notification title as well as the notification message in the Java class (not an Activity class):

```
// Display a sync success or failure notification.
public static void displaySyncEndNoti(Context mContext) {
    ...
    sBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext);

    sBuilder.setContentTitle(strContentTitle);
    sBuilder.setContentText(strContentText);
    ...
    sBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(strContentTitle));
    sBuilder.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(strContentText));
}
```

I used the bigText method so that when the text is too long, it moves the sentence to the next line when it gets cut off. So, the bigText worked for the notification message, but it doesn't seem to work for the notification title ("AT&T Address Book Sync Incomplete") as the following notification shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnT4.png

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is a limited amount of space for notifications, and how much space is controlled by the system (roughly 1 "title" line and 3 "text" lines).  You cannot include arbitrary amounts of text and expect it to "fit".  Using a custom notification with "marquee" may work, see poster below.  Note that custom layouts are subject to the exact same overall space limitations as "regular" notifications.  The latest Android version allows for separate "short" and "long" versions of notification, try that out.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works, if it worked mark it as a correct thanks